# design android app with two views

Tags: java, android, xml

this is my project goals and what I have to write:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ND9j.png)

I designed XML interface files.
page 1:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.android.mytodolist.MainActivity">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAddItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add New"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:onClick="onAddItemClick"/>


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/itemList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnAddItem" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

and this is second page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.android.mytodolist.MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSaveItem"
    android:layout_width="128dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:text="Save"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:onClick="onAddItemClick"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnCancelItem"
    android:layout_width="128dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:text="Cancel"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:onClick="onCancelItemClick"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtNewItem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:hint="New Item" />
```

for task 1.2 i Add this code:

```
    public void onAddItemClick(View view) {

    Intent main2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
    MainActivity.this.startActivity(main2);
}
```

i need help to write rest of code, especially how to come up with arryList and arryAdaptor so user can see result of saved items on first page and add or edit items on second page and adding time to edit text and also save and cancel button.

if anyone can help me with that it will be appreciated.

Comment: You are in off track. Don't consider other to write code for you in this site. Visit: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

To take some data to another Activity, you can put the data in a Bundle object and then put that Bundle object to the intent and then get that bundle in another activity and then get those data from there? What do you actually want to do? Tell me?

Creating the Bundle from the First Activity.

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, Example.class);
 Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
 mBundle.putString(key, value);
 mIntent.putExtras(mBundle);
```

In the second Activity to get the data, you can write this.

```
String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString(key)
```